# Ubuntu's `dpkg` ignores `Replaces` field of a package

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, deb

I'm building a newer replacement for a package, `libgpg-error`. Ubuntu also has a `libgpg-error0`, which is depended upon by system packages (such as `systemd`). My package provides everything `libgpg-error0` does, therefore I list the following:

```
Package: libgpg-error
Version: 1.35-1
...
Conflicts: libgpg-error, libgpg-error-dev, libgpg-error0
Provides: libgpg-error0, libgpg-error, libgpg-error-dev
Replaces: libgpg-error, libgpg-error-dev, libgpg-error0
```

However, dpkg refuses to upgrade to it cleanly. What am I missing?

The resulting deb can be seen [here](https://github.com/smaslennikov/packages/releases/download/v1.1.2/libgpg-error_1.35-1_amd64.deb), and the (`fpm-cook`) code for it [here](https://github.com/smaslennikov/packages/blob/master/libgpg-error/recipe.rb#L16).

Cheers!

EDIT:

This answer seems to be applicable: https://serverfault.com/a/429226, though in the same question another answer is present stating provides do allow versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#virtual-packages-provides), `Provides` cannot, in fact, have a version, therefore is ignored by `Depends`. I'll be renaming my package just for Ubuntu in this case to satisfy this dependency.

According to [dpkg changelog](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.18.24_changelog) (which is no longer available), Provides do now allow versioning and this *should* work, but when I tried it did not (with version 1.19.0.5).